# Duplicate files while compiling SCSS file to CSS files in compass

Tags: css, sass, compass

I am compiling SCSS files to CSS files using compass, but after compiling I'm getting duplicates in CSS file. Is there a way to compile without getting the duplicates?

Comment: It would help if you show us an example of what source is giving you duplicates.

Comment: It is a source that has two import files. FYI i m using compass 1.1.0 and saas 3.4